# Підлокітник чи підлікотник?

Tags: правопис

Дуже багато разів чула кілька варіантів слова: "підлікотник" і "підлокітник".

В академічному тлумачному словнику знайшла лише варіант "підлокітник":
ПІДЛОКІ́ТНИК, а, чол. Поруччя, бильця крісла, на які, сидячи, спираються ліктями.

Чи існує слово "підлікотник"?

P.S.: В українській мові - лІкоть, а не лОкоть.

Comment: Бажано крашче навести чому не [_локоть_](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=48323&page=1524).

Comment: @follower бо застаріле? Чи ви кажете, що треба вказати на застарілість?

Comment: @P.Vovk Ну не знају, можливо? Бо тут таке враженньа, шчо _локоть_ взагалі не украјиньське. Навіть јакшчо застаріле, то це теж не може бути арґументом на невживаність јого в иншому слові, јак складова частина.

Answer (score 1):

[часткова відповідь]

Як зазначалося вище у коментарі, відповідь до цього питання криється у твірному слові. 
Оскільки [лікоть](http://sum.in.ua/s/likotj) - це

> **ЛІ́КОТЬ,** ктя, чол.
>
> 1. Місце з'єднання плечової кістки з кістками передпліччя, де згинається рука.
> 2. Частина рукава одягу, що облягає місце, де згинається рука. У неї були продерті лікті, либонь ніколи було й залатати (Леся Українка, III, 1952, 707).
> 3. Старовинна міра довжини, приблизно в півметра. Поруччя було невисоке, півтора ліктя понад вулицею (Іван Франко, III, 1950, 31).

[Локіть, ЛО́КОТЬ, ктя, чол., діал.](http://sum.in.ua/s/lokitj)

> 1. іст. Давня міра довжини, що дорівнює приблизно довжині ліктьової кістки людини. Не простого — лляного полотна триддять локтів узяла (Українські народні думи.., 1955, 21); Шинок стояв.. майже [на] локоть нижче від рівня вулиці (Іван Франко, II, 1950, 9).
> 2. Лікоть (у 1 знач.). Близько локіть — та не вкусиш (Номис, 1864, № 5395); На землю шапку положивши, По локоть руки засукав [Ентелл] (Іван Котляревський, I, 1952, 95).

Оскільки **локоть, лікоть ** - це діалектизми, то, логічніше б нормативним мало бути **підлікотник**. До речі в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidlikotnyk/komentari) знаходимо коментар щодо правильності утворення цього слова, та  на жаль, відповіді немає.

Обговорення цього питання також можна поглянути на сайті [Форум СЛОВНИК](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/lofiversion/index.php?t4784.html).

Очевидно, слово **ЛОКОТЬ (ЛОКІТЬ)** нормативна українська мова витіснила, а з похідними не все так просто. Оскільки, на позначення одного значення використовувалося колись 2 слова. ([Етимологічний словник](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) т.3, с. 261).